# nhibernate "Exception occurred getter of XYZ"

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate

I'm a newbie trying to get into nHibernate and I'm having a heck of a time. I'm getting the following exception (and inner exception)

Exception occurred getter of Common32.ExtractionCompany.ID

Object does not match target type.

Basically since I'm get getting started, I have a number of classes that are supposed to have another instance of a class stored in a list. A stores B's which stores C's, etc. I'm using GUIDs as the keys so in Oracle 11g (my database) I'm using Raw(16) as the data type. What's weird is that this partially works. If I put a number of B objects in an A, everything is fine. Once I try to put C objects in B, everything breaks then.

Here is my SQL to create the target tables. Every table has an ID column as the primary key and a column that is a foreign key back to the previous table.

```
create table ExtractionCommand 
( ID Raw(16) );

create table ExtractionCompany
( ID Raw(16),
CommandID Raw(16) );

create table ExtractionTable
( ID Raw(16),
CompanyID Raw(16) );

create table ExtractionColumn
( ID Raw(16),
TableID Raw(16) );

create table ExtractionTarget
( ID Raw(16),
ColumnID Raw(16));
```

Here are my C# classes.

```
[Serializable]
public class ExtractionCommand
{
    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
    private IList<ExtractionCompany> m_company = new List<ExtractionCompany>();
    public virtual IList<ExtractionCompany> Company
    {
        get { return m_company; }
        set { m_company = value; }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ExtractionCompany
{
    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid CommandID { get; set; }
    private IList<ExtractionTable> m_tables = new List<ExtractionTable>();
    public virtual IList<ExtractionTable> Tables
    {
        get { return m_tables; }
        set { m_tables = value; }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ExtractionTable
{
    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid CompanyID { get; set; }
    private IList<ExtractionColumn> m_columns = new List<ExtractionColumn>();
    public virtual IList<ExtractionColumn> Columns
    {
        get { return m_columns; }
        set { m_columns = value; }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ExtractionColumn
{
    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid TableID { get; set; }
    public virtual ExtractionTarget Target { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ExtractionTarget
{
    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid ColumnID { get; set; }
    public virtual string TargetTable { get; set; }
    public virtual string TargetColumn { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the C# code that makes the call to save to the database (Oracle 11g).

```
ExtractionCommand cmd = new ExtractionCommand();
cmd.ID = Guid.NewGuid();

ExtractionCompany c1 = new ExtractionCompany();                    
cmd.Company.Add(c1);

ExtractionTable t1 = new ExtractionTable();
c1.Tables.Add(t1);

session.Save(cmd);
transaction.Commit();
```

And my mapping

```
<class name="ExtractionCommand" table="ExtractionCommand" >
<id name="ID">
  <generator class="guid" />
</id>    
<bag name="Company" cascade="all">
  <key column="CommandID" />
  <one-to-many class="ExtractionCompany"/>
</bag>
</class>

<class name="ExtractionCompany" table="ExtractionCompany" >
<id name="ID">
  <generator class="guid" />
</id>
<property name="CommandID"/>    
<bag name="Tables" cascade="all">
  <key column="CompanyID" />
  <one-to-many class="ExtractionCompany"/>
</bag>
</class>

<class name="ExtractionTable" table="ExtractionTable" >
<id name="ID">
  <generator class="guid" />
</id>
<property name="CompanyID"/>
<bag name="Columns" cascade="all">
  <key column="TableID"/>
  <one-to-many class="ExtractionColumn"/>
</bag>
</class>

<class name="ExtractionColumn" table="ExtractionColumn" >
<id name="ID">
  <generator class="guid" />
</id>
<property name="TableID" />
<one-to-one name="Target" class="ExtractionTarget"/>
</class>

<class name="ExtractionTarget" table="ExtractionTarget" >
<id name="ID">
  <generator class="guid" />
</id>
<property name="TargetTable"/>
<property name="TargetColumn"/>
</class>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.
mj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It breaks because you are using the wrong type in the `one-to-many` part of the `ExtractionCompany` mapping. You need to use `ExtractionTable` instead:

```
<class name="ExtractionCompany" table="ExtractionCompany" >
<id name="ID">
  <generator class="guid" />
</id>
<property name="CommandID"/>    
<bag name="Tables" cascade="all">
  <key column="CompanyID" />
  <one-to-many class="ExtractionTable"/>
</bag>
</class>
```

---

Additionally:

Your classes shouldn't contain the ID of the parent. If they really need a reference to the parent add a property with the type of the parent and map it as a reference.

Comment: Good points. I would also mention that generally you should not be serializing your nhibernate entities.  If you are using lazy loading this will not work.  Generally I think the accepted solution here is to use Dtos.